# Dropping a number of columns in a pandas DataFrame on one line

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Greetings so I have a pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
    Product_Code  W0  W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8      ...        \
806         P815   0   0   1   0   0   2   1   0   0      ...         
807         P816   0   1   0   0   1   2   2   6   0      ...         
808         P817   1   0   0   0   1   1   2   1   1      ...         
809         P818   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1      ...         
810         P819   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0      ...         

     Normalized 42  Normalized 43  Normalized 44  Normalized 45  \
806           0.00           0.33           0.33           0.00   
807           0.43           0.43           0.57           0.29   
808           0.50           0.00           0.00           0.50   
809           0.00           0.00           0.00           0.50   
810           0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00
```

but I don't need these columns as a matter of fact I need only W0 and W4, So I wanna remove all of them so this is what I tried:

```
raw_data = [ raw_data.drop( [i], 1, inplace = True )  for i in raw_data if i is not 'W0' and i is not  'W4'  ]
```

after half an hour I figured out that for some reason that `!=` does not work strings `and I was wondering why?` so I have a stable solution:

```
#WORKS !!!!
# for i in raw_data:
#     if i != 'W0' and i != 'W4':
#         raw_data.drop( [i], 1, inplace = True )
```

But I don't like it at all and I have commented it because it takes a lot of space and it's not beautiful, I want to make the one-line loop if expression to work, is it possible, the problem is that:

```
  raw_data = [ raw_data.drop( [i], 1, inplace = True )  for i in raw_data if i != 'W0' and i != 'W4'  ]
```

tries to convert the DataFrame to a list, how should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
raw_data.drop([i for i in raw_data if i is not 'W0' and i is not  'W4'], 
               axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This answers the question but the condition that you state doesn't make sense. The condition you have put is `if i is not 'W0' and i is not  'W4'`, this is going to be true always. You probably need to look at the condition again.

Comment: Yes, I thought that `!=` is equivalent to `is not`

Comment: Umm it is. You are probably looking for the or operator instead of and

Comment: not it's not it's not working with `is not`, I am looking for and because `if i is W0 => i is not w0(False) and i is not W4(True) =>` expression is `False` => we don't drop that column

Comment: @ClockSlave Absolutely not. `!=` and `is not` are very different.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, woh more than a year and still didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 raw_data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, index=your_index, columns=['W0', 'W4'])
```